# HTML/CSS textbox text color

Tags: html, css, input, colors

Using the VS Code Live Server extension and Chrome. For some reason I can change all other properties of the textbox, but not the text color-- why?

textbox.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search Google</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="textbox.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
    </body>
</html>
```

textbox.css:

```
#search-box {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `color` property only styles the text a user types into the form field. To color the *placeholder* text, you need to use the `::placeholder` pseudo-element:

```css
#search-box {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: red;
  color: blue;
}

::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the input text colors, but you can't change the placeholder text colors. If you want to set the placeholder text colors, you can do the following:

```js
#search-box::placeholder {
     color: blue;
}
```